# Power of a Mann Whitney test compared to a t test

Tags: anova, t-test, statistical-power, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

So a Mann Whitney U test is supposedly about 95% as powerful as a t-test when t-test assumptions of normality and homogeneous variance are satisfied. I also know that a Mann Whitney U test is more powerful than a t-test when these assumptions are not satisfied. My question is, is a Mann Whitney test on data where assumptions aren't satisfied as or almost powerful as a t-test on data where assumptions are satisfied?

I'm asking because I often see people doing power calculations based on the assumption that they will perform a t test. After they collect the data, they explore data and decide to use a Mann Whitney test instead and don't really revisit how changing the test affected power.

Thanks!

Comment: "*I also know that a Mann Whitney U test is more powerful than a t-test when these assumptions are not satisfied*". That's too strong a statement. Let's say the data were uniformly distributed (for example). You say you know that in those circumstances a *U* test is more powerful than the *t*, but it's not the case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1) The Mann-Whitney test is not guaranteed to be  more powerful than a t-test when the assumptions of the t-test are not satisfied, although for the sorts of violations we *tend* to see in the real world, it is.  Consider a standard Normal distribution truncated at +/- 100 and a difference between means of two groups of 0.01; this isn't Normal, but both tests will perform as if it were, since the difference between the two distributions is so small.

2) The t-test is the uniformly most powerful test for difference between means of two Normal variates blah blah blah, so it isn't going to be beaten by the Mann-Whitney on that kind of data no matter what. However, the worst that the Mann-Whitney can ever perform relative to the t-test is about 0.864 in terms of asymptotic relative efficiency, i.e., it would require 1/0.864x as much data to give the same power (asymptotically.)  ([Hollander and Wolfe](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471190454), Nonparametric Statistical Methods.)  There isn't any bound going the other way.  Reproducing some numbers from Hollander and Wolfe, for different distributions we get an A.R.E. of the M-W to the t-test of:

1. Normal: 0.955
2. Uniform: 1.0 <- also a counterexample to the M-W being better than the t for non-normal dist'ns
3. Logistic: 1.097
4. Double Exponential: 1.5
5. Exponential: 3.0
6. Cauchy (well that's easy): $\infty$

The point of course being that you can't shoot yourself in the foot by using the Mann-Whitney test instead of the t-test, but the converse is not true.

Comment: Why is Cauchy easy? And why is ARE 0? For finite N, the relative efficiency can't be $\inf$, because the power of the t-test isn't 0. But with infinite N, the variance of the distribution is undefined.  That Cauchy sure is perverse!

Comment: @PeterFlom Interesting indeed!  The difference between the limiting value and the value at the limit rears its head; the Pitman ARE is the former, not the latter.

Comment: @PeterFlom ARE relates to the ratio of the second derivatives ("curvature") of the power curves at the null, as sample size goes to infinity. It's possible for a power curve to have zero second derivative there. In practice, small to moderate-size samples, the two sample t does kind of okay at the Cauchy if you don't mind your significance levels being a lot lower than the nominal values.

Comment: So in other words, let's say I was lazy and didn't want to check my assumptions of normality etc. and just decided to go ahead and use a MW test instead of a t-test. I could use the MW test and say that, at worst I would need 1/0.864x as much data to achieve that same level of power as a t test where all assumptions were met. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Jimj no, that's not what it means.  You could use the MW test and say that (in large samples) at worst you would need 1/0.864 times as much data to achieve that same level of power as a t test *on data sets from the same distribution* (that 0.864 doesn't happen when all the assumptions of the t are met... when they are, the ARE is 0.955)

Comment: Ok I see, if you were comparing data from two distributions, things would become very tricky. Thanks so much for clearing that up.

Answer (score 10):

> is a Mann Whitney test on data where assumptions aren't satisfied as or almost powerful as a t-test on data where assumptions are satisfied?

A phrase like 'as powerful' doesn't really work as a general statement.

Power isn't especially comparable across different distributional models. The size of a given effect has different meanings in different parts of the distribution. Imagine you have a distribution that is pretty peaked, but has a heavy tail; by what measure to we say a particular size of deviation is similar to something with a much 'flatter' centre and smaller tail? A small deviation might be about as easy to pick up, but a large deviation might be (relative to the other distributional possibility we're trying to compare power for) harder.

With two possible sets of normal distributions, one pair with a large s.d. and one with a small s.d., it's easy to say 'well, power will just scale with standard deviation; if we define our effect size in terms of number of standard deviations, we can relate the two power curves'.

But now with differently *shaped* distributions, there's no obvious scale choice. We must make some choices about how to compare them. What choices we make will determine how they "compare".

For example, how do I compare power when the data are Cauchy with power when the data are say a scaled beta(2,2)? What is a comparable effect size? The Cauchy below has more of its distribution between -1 and 1 and less of its distribution between -3 and 3 than the other one. Their interquartile ranges are different, for example. What is our basis for comparison?

[image: Cauchy vs scaled beta]

If you can resolve that conundrum, now consider if one of the distributions is skewed left and the other is bimodal, or any of a myriad number of other possibilities.

You can still compute power under any particular set of assumptions, but comparison of one test across different distributional assumptions rather than two tests under a given distributional assumption is conceptually very tricky.