# How is power for t test and Mann Whitney comparable when null hypotheses differ

Tags: anova, statistical-power, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

[In a previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71302/power-of-a-mann-whitney-test-compared-to-a-t-test), I asked about comparing the power of a t test to a Mann Whitney test under different situations. One of the answers pointed out that the worst that the Mann-Whitney can ever perform relative to the t-test is that it would require 1/0.864x as much data to give the same power as the t test so long as the data sets being compared were from the same distribution.

I guess I am confused about how power can be compared between these two tests given that they test different null hypotheses. For example, if I estimate the power for a t-test at 0.9 using effect size equal to a 20% difference between means, then that makes sense for a t test. But a Mann Whitney test does not test for differences between means. If the distributions were the same it would test for differences between medians. Am I right in thinking that the Mann Whitney test would require 1/0.864x as much data to detect a 20% difference in medians with a power of 0.9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) It's important to distinguish between an estimator and the population quantity it is being used to estimate.

For example, for a symmetric distribution whose mean exists, I could use any number of sample estimators of the population mean - such as the sample median, for example. [And, for example, if the distribution is Laplace, the sample median is actually a substantially better estimate of the population *mean* than the sample mean is.]

2) If you assume the same distribution-shape (i.e. identical apart from a possible location shift) for the two populations in your test, then both the Mann-Whitney and the t-test test for that location shift, which is the same shift whether you think of it as a shift in means, medians, 95th percentiles or whatever.

In that situation, the Mann-Whitney is as much a test of difference in populations means as the t-test is, it just uses a different estimator for the quantity. Indeed, it's quite possible to produce both an estimate of (and interval for) that shift under either test.

The Mann-Whitney estimate of the shift is the median of pairwise cross-sample differences ([see the second paragraph here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodges%E2%80%93Lehmann_estimator)) -- but similar to the example in (1), that's a perfectly valid way to estimate the shift in population *means*.

For more discussion of some of these issues, and how a Mann-Whitney and a t-test test the same null and alternative hypothesis once you assume that the alternative is location-shift, see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/67204/what-exactly-does-a-non-parametric-test-accomplish-what-do-you-do-with-the-res/67210#67210)